# How to get rid of space kept by text with line break?

Tags: css

I've got two elements (let's say an image and a text) in a `<div>` that I center using flexbox.

The problem is that the text takes extra space when a line break occur because of a long word.

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.image {
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">IMG</div>
  <p>Word word word</p>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image">IMG</div>
  <p>Word word word verylongword</p>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image">IMG</div>
  <div>
    <p style="display:inline">Word word word verylongword</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/34q2hrta/1/)

In the first case, there is no line break and elements are well positioned. In the second case a long word create a line break and the `<p>` keep the remaining space.

That's what I expected:

[image]

I tried to enclose the text in another `<div>` and make it `display: inline;` (third case) but the space is still present.

Any idea ?

Comment: short answer: you cannot control this